# MySQL partitioning or NoSQL like AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, database-partitioning

**Business logic:**

My application crawls a lot(hundreds or sometimes thousands) of webpages every few hours and stores all the links(i.e. all anchor tags) on that webpage in a **MySQL** database table say `links`. This table is growing very big day by day (already around 20 million records as of now).

**Technical:**

I have a unique index combined on [`webpage_id`, `link`] in the `links` table. Also, I have a column `crawl_count` in the same table.
Now whenever I crawl a webpage, I already know `webpage_id` (the foreign key to `webpages` table) and I get links in that webpage (i.e. array of `link`) which I just do an insert or update query without worrying about what is already in the table.

```
INSERT INTO ........ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE crawl_count=crawl_count+1
```

**Problem:**

The table grows big every day & I want to optimize the table for performance. Options I considered are,

- Partitioning: Partition table by domains. All webpages belong to a particular domain. For example: Webpage https://www.amazon.in/gp/goldbox?ref_=nav_topnav_deals belong to the domain https://www.amazon.in/
- NoSQL like DynamoDB. I have other tables of application in MySQL DB which I do not want to migrate to DynamoDB unless it's absolutely required. Also I have considered change in application logic (eg: change the structure of `webpages` table to something like

```
{webpage: "http://example.com/new-brands", links: [link1, link2, link3]}
```

and migrate this table to DynamoDB so I don't have a `links` table. But again, there is a limit for every record in DynamoDB(400kb). What if it exceeds this limit?

I have read pros & cons of using either of the approach. As far my understanding goes, DynamoDB doesn't seem to be a good fit for my situation. But still wanted to post this question so I can make a good decision for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PARTITION BY domain` -- No.  There won't be any performance gain.  Anyway, you will find that one domain dominates the table, and a zillion domains show up only once.  (I'm speaking from experience.)

The only concept of an "array" is a separate table.  It would have, in your case, `webpage_id` and `link` as a 2-column `PRIMARY KEY` (which is 'unique').

Normalize.  This is to avoid having lots of copies of each domain and each link.  This saves some space.

I assume you have two categories of links -- the ones for pages you have scanned, and the ones for pages waiting to scan.  And probably the two sets are similar in size.  I don't understand the purpose of `crawl count, but it adds to the cost.

I may be able to advise further if I could see the queries -- both inserting and selecting.  Also, how big are the tables (GB) and what is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Putting these together, we can discuss likely points if sluggishness.

Also the slowlog would help.

Are you dealing with non-ascii urls?  Urls too long to index?  Do you split urls into domain + path?  Do you strip off "#..."?  And "?..."?